# Мое приложение на .net core 5 завершает работу с ошибкой при попытке получить идентификатор оборудования на Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, .net, windows-7, core

Я разрабатываю приложение на .net core 5 для использования в Windows 10, но появилась необходимость добавить поддержку Windows 7 и я столкнулся с проблемой.
Приложение работает нормально, но при попытке получить идентификатор оборудования возникает ошибка:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 5.0.1321.56516
.NET Version: 5.0.13
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (126): Failed to load required native library 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\wminet_utils.dll'.
   at System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.MTAHelper.IsNoContextMTA()
   at System.Management.MTAHelper.CreateInMTA(Type type)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(String path)
   ...
```

Код:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new("Select ProcessorId From Win32_processor"); // <- Ошибка
ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = mbs.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
{
   id += mo["ProcessorId"].ToString();
}
```

Я установил следующие пакеты обновлений, но это не решило проблему:

```
KB4457144
KB2999226
KB3063858
```

.net framework 4.0 тоже установлен

Comment: Этот же код скомпилированный на .net framework 4.0 и запущенный на Windows 7 выполняется успешно

Comment: А если установить .NET Framework 4.7.2 ?

Comment: Это помогло! Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было установить .NET Framework 4.7.2
Спасибо **EvgeniyZ**

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы использовать WMI и не зависеть от .NET Framework и иметь возможность собирать ваш проект self-contained, попробуйте эту библиотеку
https://github.com/MartinKuschnik/WmiLight
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WmiLight/

Автор её специально написал [из соображений производительности](https://github.com/MartinKuschnik/WmiLight#in-which-case-should-you-use-wmilight):

> У реализации .Net framework есть одна большая проблема. При каждой удаленной операции происходит небольшая утечка памяти. Используйте эту структуру, если ваше приложение является службой или работает долго, и вы отправляете много удаленных запросов.

Но нам (мне) она пригодится, чтобы избавиться от зависимости на .NET Framework.